# swapping to columns ended up with blank table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with 15 columns and 2 rows. I decided to swap the Month and Year columns so I run following query:

```
UPDATE test_schema.my_table_name 
SET volume = month_value,
month_value=year_value,
year_value=volume
;
```

Volume column was empty so I used it as a temporary column. When I run the code all the table got empty!All 15 columns! would you please let me know why this happened?

The table was just a test table, is there any way to get the data back after running a wrong query?or the data is lost permanently?

Comment: No temp column should be needed, simply do `UPDATE tablename
SET col1 = col2,
col2 = col1`.

Comment: Do you want to swap values between **rows** or between **columns**?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just want to swap values of month and year columns

Comment: @jarlh sorry it is not the right answer. By following your query, both columns will have column 2 value and column 1 will be lost

Comment: @saba: Postgres is not MySQL, jarlh's  statement **will** work. No intermediate column necessary.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for your comment I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for an temporary column, you can just swap the two columns:

```
UPDATE test_schema.my_table_name 
   SET year_value = month_value,
       month_value = year_value;
```

This **will** work as the right side of an assignment is evaluate before the update is run.

Online example: https://rextester.com/TIYDE85991

Answer (score 1):

It' strange that  jarlh's proposal did not work, try 3 statements:

```
UPDATE test_schema.my_table_name 
SET volume = month_value;
UPDATE test_schema.my_table_name 
SET month_value=year_value;
UPDATE test_schema.my_table_name 
SET year_value=volume;
```